# The tensor product of two riemannian metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

let $g=(g_{ij})$ and $h=(h_{ij})$ be two Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. consider the Riemannian metric $g\otimes h$ as a metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

> how can we describe  the geometry of the later metric in terms of two initial metrics?Is there any relation between the isometry group of the tensor metric and the isometry groups of the initial metrics?What is a relation between LC connections of these metrics?What is the result of the tensor product of two flat metrics?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez  i do not have any idea on the isometric group of the tensor metric. i did not computed the details of the last two parts of the question.

Comment: Did you compute anything regarding the other parts of your question?